# How to create a chat usable from differents computers in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am currently learning node.js and I've just finished the chat using socket.io and express.js which works well. But now I'd like to expand this chat so that two users from differents computers could communicate.

I think it might be easier, first, using two computers on the same network but then I'd like the app to enable communication between two computers (each on a different network).

Is it possible using socket.io ? If yes, how ?

I guess there's something to change here :

```
server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

If someone knows how, please let me know !

Thanks

Comment: You have to deploy you application on remote server.

Comment: No need to configure different IP's, When i request comes to NodeJS server IP, Using Socket.io you can start  chat, if you are using Node js as a Rest API in that case you have to set header in order to avoid Cross origin.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to host your nodeJS application to a web server, giving everyone access to your website.

To achieve that you will need to use Cloud Application Platform, like [AmazonWebService](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/free/), or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com). You will be able to host your nodeJS application to a server same as you do to develop but it will be online.

You could follow theses tutorials :

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets
- https://hackernoon.com/deploying-a-node-app-on-amazon-ec2-d2fb9a6757eb
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

You can found more with this google search :

"deploy node js app nginx"

Good luck.